# Oracle trigger which doesn't work

Tags: oracle, triggers

I've create a trigger which work on 2 tables like this:
- when insert a new row on table A (GEDDFILES) then a number field on table B(GEDDIRS) will be increased.

Code is getting compiled without errors but it doesn't work. the code is bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "A"."TRGMAJNRFIC" AFTER
INSERT ON "A"."GEDFILES" FOR EACH ROW DECLARE 
 wtmpnrfic number;

BEGIN 
 SELECT MAX(OBJNRFICHIERS) INTO wtmpnrfic from GEDDirs WHERE ID= :new.ID;
 UPDATE GEDDirs SET OBJNRFICHIERS = wtmpnrfic+1 WHERE ID=:new.id;
END;
```

Tables are normalized and PK from GEDDIRS(field ID) is FK in table GEDFILES (field ID)

I can't figure out where is the problem, even is a little one.

The field OBJNRFICHIERS from table GEDFILES is null. Can be this a problem when i'm trying to increase it's value?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to maintain a "count of records" in a table. You should realise that this will not work in the presence of concurrent sessions adding new rows to `GEDFILES` for the same `GEDDirs.ID`. The data in `OBJNRFICHIERS` will likely become rubbish.

Comment: yes, you're right! and how should i resolve this? can you give an alternative solution?

best regards,

Comment: Add DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tirgger works' ); for your trigger and connect to dmbs output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved it. the problem was that the field OBJNRFICHIERS was null. the trigger code is bellow

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "A"."TRGMAJNRFIC" AFTER
INSERT ON "A"."GEDFILES" FOR EACH ROW DECLARE 
 wtmpnrfic number;

BEGIN 
 SELECT MAX(OBJNRFICHIERS) INTO wtmpnrfic from GEDDirs WHERE ID= :new.ID;
 IF wtmpnrfic IS NULL then wtmpnrfic :=0;
 ELSE wtmpnrfic := wtmpnrfic+1;
 UPDATE GEDDirs SET OBJNRFICHIERS = wtmpnrfic+1 WHERE ID=:new.id;
 END IF;
END;
```

thank you all for the suggestions, and also other suggestions are welcomed! +1 for all the answers

Answer (score 4):

Simple question: Have you enabled your trigger?

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/enable.php

Edit: Now I saw that you described that OBJNRFICHIERS from table GEDFILES is null. Put 0 (zero) on that column and run a test... Probably this is the problem! :)

Comment: Yes. I enabled now the trigger and run also a "commit". 

i've made a test now and doesn't work.

Comment: After inserting a row on table GEDDFILES are you commiting?

Comment: Have you inserted the value 0 in column OBJNRFICHIERS from table GEDFILES?

Comment: I didn't saw your post, but this was what i've done and now it's working. the solution is bellow. 

Thanks!

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect place to use NVL2 to make the code a bit cleaner:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "A"."TRGMAJNRFIC"
  AFTER INSERT ON "A"."GEDFILES"
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE  
  wtmpnrfic number;  
BEGIN  
  SELECT MAX(OBJNRFICHIERS)
    INTO wtmpnrfic
    from GEDDirs
    WHERE ID = :new.ID; 

  UPDATE GEDDirs
    SET OBJNRFICHIERS = NVL2(wtmpnrfic, 0, wtmpnrfic+1);
    WHERE ID = :new.ID; 
  END IF; 
END;
```

Or, if you like, you could use COALESCE to replace the NVL2 line above:

```
    SET OBJNRFICHIERS = COALESCE(wtmpnrfic+1, 0);
```

Or, I suppose, NVL would work just as well:

```
    SET OBJNRFICHIERS = NVL(wtmpnrfic+1, 0);
```

Share and enjoy.